# Can't get reCAPTCHA to work in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, recaptcha

I'm using the CodeIgniter reCAPTCHA library ([here](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/ReCAPTCHA/), forum [here](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/67250/)).  For some reason, no variables are being passed from the reCAPTCHA library to the view that has the reCAPTCHA field code.

Here is my controller (the pertinent parts):

```
$this->load->library('recaptcha');
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->lang->load('recaptcha');

// Validate form
...
$this->form_validation->set_rules('recaptcha_response_field','Captcha','required|callback_captcha_check');
```

And I've tried loading the field view as a variable:

```
$data['recaptcha'] = $this->load->view('recaptcha',$data,true);
```

And within my main view:

```
<?php $this->load->view('recaptcha');?>
```

Here is the view code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var RecaptchaOptions = { 
    theme:"<?= $theme ?>",
    lang:"<?= $lang ?>"
  };
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?= $server ?>/challenge?k=<?= $key.$errorpart ?>"></script>
<noscript> 
        <iframe src="<?= $server ?>/noscript?lang=<?= $lang ?>&k=<?= $key.$errorpart ?>" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br/>
        <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge"/>
</noscript>
```

The library can be found via the links above, but I think it's just a wrapper for the default reCAPTCHA PHP library.

When I access the registration form, the page loads but the reCAPTCHA widget doesn't show up  because it throws an error for every variable -- all are undefined.

I'm sure this is something basic about loading variables from a library into a view.  Can someone help me out?

Comment: When you pass the data to the view - 

$this->load->view('recaptcha', $data, true); 
or 
$this->load->view('recaptcha', $data); 

Are you setting the elements for the $data array before? 
i.e. 
$data['theme'] = 'xyz';
$data['lang'] = '..';
etc?

I'm not seeing that in your code.

Comment: I'm not sure how to assign variables from a library.  Can I just refer to them as regular variables, or do I need to reference the library object somehow?  For instance, the variable $lang is defined in the library; can I set $data['lang'] = $lang?

Comment: Take a look at the user guide. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html That will show you how to pull text from the language class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the view area of the user guide.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

It'll show you how to add dynamic data to a view. You usually would do this in your controller.